# blazor wasm authority based on subdomain

Tags: blazor-webassembly, multi-tenant, openiddict

I'm trying to build a multitenant blazor wasm and have an issue in pointing to the correct authority.

I have an openiddict identity server with finbuckle installed using basepath strategy.
This means that each tenant will have its own configuration enddpoint

- https://localhost:7065/test01/.well-known/openid-configuration
- https://localhost:7065/test02/.well-known/openid-configuration
- https://localhost:7065/test03/.well-known/openid-configuration

my blazor app should use following url's:

- test01.localhost
- test02.localhost
- test03.localhost

**question**
how can i get the subdomain and put this in the authority url?